# copy file: Not a directory

Tags: network-attached-storage, copy

I have a NAS mount, and I can copy file to this,
but I can't copy files similar to this

```
cp /home2/user/WRF/WRFV3/run/*_2 . -v
`/home2/user/WRF/WRFV3/run/wrfout_d04_2007-11-21_00:00:00_2' -> `./wrfout_d04_2007-11-21_00:00:00_2'
cp: cannot create regular file `./wrfout_d04_2007-11-21_00:00:00_2': Not a directory
```

I get this error.

#### EDIT

when I try make a file with `:` in the name, I get a error

```
$ date >> file\:file
-bash: file:file: Not a directory
```

but this command work in my home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NAS server is running samba/smb/cifs then it may object to colons (:) in file names (subject to mapchars being set).

Answer (score 0):

You receive the error when you try to copy a symbolic link.

Do you want copy also the symbolic link?

If the answer is yes use the flag "-d"

> -d, --no-dereference 
>                 Copy symbolic links as symbolic links rather than copying the files 
>                 that  they  point  to, and preserve hard link relationships between 
>                 source files in the copies.

Comment: the files are regular files, in the directory not exist a symbolic link